# In Java how to programatically kill process on a specified port in Windows

Tags: java

Basically I am automation an application and prerequisite of my automation is that I am using several 3rd party libs which starts certain processes. At the end of the code execution, I want to close all such processes. The only thing I know is that these process runs on specific port always (for example 61120).

As part of clean up, I want to close the process running on port 61120 programatically in Java.

Comment: and what have you tried... show some code... it may be easier to help...

Comment: You can also check the Parent Process ID, IMHO that is more reliable than some network ports. Anyway Java is the wrong language for such a tool.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `netstat -a -b` to get the executables and the port numbers. After that you can `taskkill` the executables by name. But i never would use this on a productive machine because it's some kind of ...ahm... dangerous.

Better to start processes by java (`Runtime.getRuntime().execute(...)`) and end them if you do not need them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Through this you can get the desired processes and port numbers
 netstat -a -b

Then there is a little API providing the desired functionality to operate with the processes:

https://java.net/projects/winp

Windows Process Library

Answer (score 0):

try
netstat -a -o -n
Search for the port you need.
If the console output is more then re-direct it to some file like:
netstat -a -o -n > {drive}:/netlog.log 
search port in that log file.

taskkill /F /PID